# Using multiple fields as parameters in QGIS Processing Algorithm Script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, parameters

I have a script looks like this:

```py
##Input_Layer=vector
##Date_Field=field Input_Vector

# Do Something...
```

So normally it would like one vector layer and one field, and the choice of field would be depend on the Input_Layer. However I want to make it to take multiple fields.

I should be looking for something like "multiple raster" or "multiple vector" as shown below. It allows user to input as many as they want. But there is no "multiple field". Is there a way to do that?

[image: 2.8]

Comment: You can achieve this in the latest versions of QGIS. You asked several questions for QGIS 2.8, most of which can only be solved with workarounds. In this scenario, unless you set a fixed amount of field parameters, I don't think you can set multiple field inputs using QGIS 2.8...